# "Overloaded" type-safe function

Tags: function, haskell, overloading, type-safety

I'm trying to come up with a definition of a function that can be applied like this:

```
setProperty Left 45 Px
setProperty Position Absolute
setProperty Visible True
```

I tried `GADTs`:

```
data StyleUnit = Px | Pct | Em
data PositionP = Absolute | Relative | Static

data Property a where
  Position :: Property PositionP
  Left :: Property (Integer -> StyleUnit)
  Visible :: Bool
```

using the following signature:

```
setProperty :: Property a -> a -> IO ()
```

but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. Is this at all achievable, or am I better off just having specialized function versions, like `setPropertyPosition`, `setPropertyLeft` and so on?

Answer (score 1):

You can use TypeFamilies to work around this. This is suggested only when these have similar semantics, otherwise their use might confuse the user. I am not sure about your types, so I have modified them a little in the following example implementation.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

data StyleUnit = Px | Pct | Em
data PositionP = Absolute | Relative | Static
data Visible = Visible

class Property a where
  type PropertyVal a :: *
  setProperty :: (PropertyVal a) -> a -> IO ()

instance Property StyleUnit where
  type PropertyVal StyleUnit = Either Int Int
  setProperty a _ = print a

instance Property PositionP where
  type PropertyVal PositionP = ()
  setProperty a _ = print a

instance Property Visible where
  type PropertyVal Visible = Bool
  setProperty a _ = print a
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm first trying to explain what's going on in the code from the question, and then suggest looking into lenses as an alternative solution.

#### An easy to fix compile error

First, your data definition produces an error because the type of `Visible` does not end in `Property`. You want this instead:

```
data Property a where
  Position :: Property PositionP
  Left :: Property (Integer -> StyleUnit)
  Visible :: Property Bool
```

#### A problem with `Left`

Now you could write the following:

```
setProperty :: Property a -> a -> IO ()
setProperty = undefined
```

But there's a problem with the type of `setProperty Left`, as you can check out in `ghci` (you probably want to `import Prelude hiding (Left)` to get this working).

```
:t setProperty Left
setProperty Left :: (Integer -> StyleUnit) -> IO ()
```

I don't think that's the type you want. You probably want `Integer -> StyleUnit -> IO ()` instead.

#### Moving `IO ()` into the data type

The easiest way to achieve that would be to move the `IO ()` into the `Property` data type:

```
data Property a where
  Position :: Property (PositionP -> IO ())
  Left :: Property (Integer -> StyleUnit -> IO ())
  Visible :: Property (Bool -> IO ())

setProperty :: Property a -> a
setProperty = undefined
```

This might work well enough for `setProperty`, but it is not clear how to write `getProperty`, which I guess you also want to have.

#### Using pairs

Maybe it's better to just use a pair of value and unit:

```
data Property a where
  Position :: Property PositionP
  Left :: Property (Integer, StyleUnit)
  Visible :: Property Bool

setProperty :: Property a -> a -> IO ()
setProperty = undefined
```

This gives you:

```
:t setProperty Left
setProperty Left :: (Integer, StyleUnit) -> IO ()
```

Which you should be able to implement.

#### Is this really the way to go?

Without knowing the background of your question, I cannot say whether this is really the way to go. It seems quite complicated technology for a simple goal. What's wrong with `setPosition`, `setLeft` and `setVisible`? If you just want to combine a setter and a getter into a single abstraction, you might want to look into lenses.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you mean by `setProperty`. If you mean *create property*, you can do something like this:

```
data StyleUnit = Px | Pct | Em
data PositionP = Absolute | Relative | Static

data Property a where
  Position :: PositionP -> Property PositionP
  Left :: (Integer,StyleUnit) -> Property (Integer, StyleUnit)
  Visible :: Bool -> Property Bool

setProperty :: (a -> Property a) -> a -> Property a
setProperty = ($)
```

Examples:

```
setProperty Left (45,Px)
```